# Starting again a Retrofit call subscribing the Observable again from onError Callback in RXJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2, onerror

When the Retrofit Call does not succeed ( for example because no Internet), is called as expected the RXJava Callback `onError`, where I have a `Snackbar` with a `setAction()` Listener indicated with an intuitive String "Retry" where I should pass a command to start again the network call. 
I could restart  the class where I am inside calling it `NameActivity()`, but this look terrible.Which command I can pass inside the `Snackbar` listener to restart the below code?

```
 MyViewModel!!.getPost("132")
            ?.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider!!.io())
            ?.observeOn(schedulerProvider!!.ui())
            ?.doOnNext {
                run {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                }
            }

            ?.subscribe(object : FlowableSubscriber<List<Post>> {
                override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)

                    spinner.visibility
                    Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout), "Check Internet Connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setAction("Retry", {})//HERE THE COMMAND SHOULD PASS
                            .show();

                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onComplete: ")
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
                    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);

                }

                override fun onNext(posts: List<Post>?) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)

                    posts?.let { viewAdapter.setTitleData(it) }

                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the snackbar right away when your call fails, you have to call the subscription again. You could refactor your code as follows:

1. Place your Rx code inside a method. e.g. `doNetworkCall()`.
2. Create a separate method to handle your errors. e.g. `handleError(t: Throwable)`.
3. Inside that method you can make your `Snackbar` appear, and call the `doNetworkCall()` method once the user taps the retry action.

Example:

```
fun doNetworkCall() {
    MyViewModel!!.getPost("132")
            ?.subscribeOn(schedulerProvider!!.io())
            ?.observeOn(schedulerProvider!!.ui())
            // The rest of the code here was removed for brevity.
             ?.subscribe(object : FlowableSubscriber<List<Post>> {
                override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                    spinner.visibility

                    handleError(t) // Call the method here.
                }
            // The rest of the code here was removed for brevity.
}

fun handleError(t: Throwable?) {
    // Here you can also check the type of the error, and perhaps even change the snackbar action depending on it.
    Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout), "Check Internet Connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Retry", doNetworkCall()) // Set the retry action to call the doNetworkCall() method again.
            .show()
}
```

You could also use automatic retries before you prompt anything to the user. That can be achieved by using the [Rx retry operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html). If your network call fails, it'll automatically subscribe again for a given number of tries.

As stated on the ReactiveX docs:

> - One variant of retry takes **no parameters**. It will continue to
>     resubscribe to and mirror the source Observable no matter how many
>     onError notifications it receives.
> - Another variant of retry takes a **single parameter**: a count of the
>     number of times it should try to resubscribe to the source Observable
>     when it encounters errors. If this count is exceeded, retry will not
>     attempt to resubscribe again and will instead pass the latest onError
>     notification to its observers.
> - A third variant of retry takes **a predicate function as a parameter**.
>     You write this function to accept two arguments: an Integer count of
>     how many retries have taken place thusfar, and a Throwable indicating
>     the error that caused the onError notification. This function returns
>     a Boolean to indicate whether or not retry should resubscribe to and
>     mirror the source Observable. If it does not, then retry passes the
>     latest onError notification to its observers.

Comment: Thanks.Well `retry` operator does not fit my use case because cannot be called from inside `SnackBar` Listener, so I would like to implement the solution you mention, but how can I implement point 2 if onError get called inside the Subscriber Callbacks  and not in a separate method, in other words is inside the `doNetworkCall()`you suggest at point one

Comment: You can create a method outside `doNetworkCall()` to handle the errors, and call this method inside the Rx's `onError`.

Comment: first of all if I wrap all the code I published I have to inject also the View so that would be `fun doNetworkCall(view:View)` because I have instance of the view for the `SnackBar` and `ProgressBar`, but the central problem is how I can isolate `onError` as a method? I am trying but as expected does not work because onError should go into a subscription to an Observable that is basically all the method `doNetworkCall(view:view)` I mean `Observable.subscribe(//here are called the 4 rxjava callBacks, and cannot isolate OnError apart!)`

Comment: amazing @Mauker is working thank you very much. Response accepted